# Issue with AWS SES for attachment with zip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I a trying to use the SES API to send an attachment as a zipped content of a csv file. The csv file is nearly 3MB in size. I am not using any SDK and doing it from the bash shell using curl and API endpoints.

The code works and I get the zip as an attachment in my mailbox too. But when I try to download the same it tells me either the file is damaged or corrupt.

$REPORTOUTFILE is the csv file

Need your help in this as I am not able to find a work around on this.

```
CURRENT_PATH=$(pwd)
zip $CURRENT_PATH/message.zip $REPORTOUTFILE
ATTACHMENT_CONTENTS=`zcat $CURRENT_PATH/message.zip`
ATTACHMENT_TEXT="stuck_order_report_tmp_$DATE.zip"
ATTACHMENT_CONTENTS_ENCODED="$(echo "$ATTACHMENT_CONTENTS" | base64)"

VALUE="To:"$TO"
Subject: Email with Attachment
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a"

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a"

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello ! This is the text content for the email body.

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a--

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: attachment/zip; name="$ATTACHMENT_TEXT"
Content-Description: "$ATTACHMENT_TEXT"
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="$ATTACHMENT_TEXT";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

$ATTACHMENT_CONTENTS_ENCODED
--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a--"

MESSAGE="$(echo "$VALUE" | base64)"
echo "$MESSAGE" > $CURRENT_PATH/message_new.txt
message="RawMessage.Data=$MESSAGE"
echo "$message" > $CURRENT_PATH/message.txt

curl  -v -X POST --trace "$CURRENT_PATH/trace.log" -H "Date: $date" -H "$auth_header" -H "$content_encoding" --data-binary "@$CURRENT_PATH/message.txt" --data-urlencode "$source" --data-urlencode "$action" "$endpoint"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet finally worked

```
## AWS SES Invocation ##
CURRENT_PATH=$(pwd)
zip $CURRENT_PATH/message.zip $REPORTOUTFILE
ATTACHMENT_TEXT="stuck_order_report_tmp_$DATE.zip"
ATTACHMENT_CONTENTS_ENCODED="$( base64  $CURRENT_PATH/message.zip )"

VALUE="To:"$TO"
Subject: Email with Attachment
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a"

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a"

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hello ! This is the text content for the email body. Whatever modification is required has to happen here.
Ensure that the boundaries values are changed. Feel free to change the last two digits only.
Remember that the same change  must reflect in both start of boundary and end of boundary.

--sub_a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a--

--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a
Content-Type: attachment/zip; name="$ATTACHMENT_TEXT"
Content-Description: "$ATTACHMENT_TEXT"
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="$ATTACHMENT_TEXT";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

$ATTACHMENT_CONTENTS_ENCODED
--a3f166a86b56ff6c37755292d690675717ea3cd9de81228ec2b76ed4a15d6d1a--"
MESSAGE="$(echo "$VALUE" | base64)"
message="RawMessage.Data=$MESSAGE"
#message_edited=${message%??}
last_two_character=${message:(-2)}
last_one_character=${message:(-1)}
echo $last_two_character
echo $last_one_character
if [ "$last_two_character" == "==" ]; then
message_edited=${message%??}
 else
message_edited=${message}
fi
if [ "$last_one_character" == "=" ]; then
message_edited=${message%??}
 else
message_edited=${message}
fi
echo "$message_edited" > $CURRENT_PATH/message.txt
chmod 777 $CURRENT_PATH/message.txt
# trigger email
curl  -v -X POST --trace "$CURRENT_PATH/trace.log" -H "Date: $date" -H "$auth_header" -H "$content_encoding" --data-binary "@$CURRENT_PATH/message.txt" --data-urlencode "$source" --data-urlencode "$action" "$endpoint"

rm -f $CURRENT_PATH/message.txt
rm -f $CURRENT_PATH/message.zip
rm -f $REPORTOUTFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Let me know if I'm correct. You are sending a csv but you want to obtain it as a .zip?

The error could be thrown because the file isn't encoded as a zip even when it's received as a zip. It's like when you try to open a pdf in word, it will show everything encrypted.

Have you tried to make the zip before you send the mail? (with the zip command or something)

Comment: Yes. I want to zip the csv file and send it across as an attachment in email. But as per SES API requirements you have to do a base 64 encode of the attachment and then send it and that is what I am doing.                                                               If at the last line I zip the content and then send it the AWS SES API will throw an error. If you think that the encoding is incorrect, can you please correct the approach.